# Select element tag and jquery - script stops working

Tags: jquery, html

I have this select tag:

```
<div class="browse_by">
     <select id="dynamic_select">  
            <option selected="selected">Browse by Category</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#dynamic_select').bind('change', function() {
    var url = $(this).val();
    if (url) {
        window.location = "/gallery/" + url;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem is when I use a custom jQuery drop down menu for this Select element, the jQuery code stops working. I tried jqtransform and dropkick.

It usually works fine when used before jqtransform and dropkick but after them it stop working no url redirection.

Any help ?

Comment: Are you doing this in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: Yes i am doing it in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using Dropkick.js which basically rewrites your `select` tag into a custom widget.
You'll need to reattach the event handler.

If you go to the [Dropkick site](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/), read up on the **Custom 'change' callback** section.

You'll need to do something like

```
$('#dynamic_select').dropkick({
  change: function (value, label) {
    var url = value;
    if (url) {
       window.location = "/gallery/" + url;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a single problem.... Your option elements do not have VALUE attribute...

`<option selected="selected">Browse by Category</option>`

Since there is no `value` attribute defined

`var url = $(this).val();`  will fail...

Hence your `window.location` will be set to `"/gallery/undefined"`

Make it like

`<option selected="selected" value="somePage.html">Browse by Category</option>`

and it will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with my library http://www.pkoretic.net/csTransPie/
It doesn't change select tag, only applies styling over it.
It works natively even on phones.